# Get email administrators using wss 3.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, wss

How could obtain all e-mail from site collection's administrators using wss 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
   private string[] GetEmails(SPWeb web)
   {
       List<string> emails = new List<string>();
       Guid siteID = web.Site.ID;
       Guid webID = web.ID;
       using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteID, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
       {
           using (SPWeb web1 = site.OpenWeb(webID))
           {
               SPUserCollection admins = web1.SiteAdministrators;
               foreach (SPUser admin in admins)
               {
                   emails.Add(admin.Email);
               }
           }
       }
       return emails.ToArray();
   }
```

Note that [SiteAdministrators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.siteadministrators.aspx) requires that the context user is a [site collection auditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.issiteauditor.aspx).